# How to locate and click on a link having javascript within the href attribute through selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I want to locate link AD04550 below is the code for AD04550

[image]

I tried below codes -

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='AD04550']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.tagName("AD04550")).click();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("AD04550")).click();
```

Please suggest.

Comment: could you post the full html tag of the element you're looking for?

Comment: what is the exception you are getting. Update the question with HTML code also.

Comment: <TD title="" class=TBLL noWrap>
<A id=1020285337 onmouseover="showDelayDiv(this.id, '/Windchill/rfa/jsp/main/Main.jsp?activity=GET_QUICK_INFO&amp;oid=VR:com.lcs.wc.product.LCSProduct:39244951')" onmouseout=stopDelayDiv() href="javascript:viewProductSkuSeason('VR:com.lcs.wc.product.LCSProduct:39244951')">AD04550</A></TD>

Comment: here id is not constant , so need to locate using href only

Comment: thanks Andrei  its working

Comment: thanks DebanjanB  , its working with linktext option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to click on the element with text as **AD04550** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

- `linkText`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("AD04550"))).click();
  ```

Comment: for xpath , getting error : Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
 - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete

Comment: @priya _LinkText_ is preferred option than _XPath_ I have removed the _xpath_

Comment: thanks ,what is purpose of WebDriverWait ? why we have to use it here ?

Comment: @priya It's pretty clear from the HTML you provided that the website contains _JavaScript_. So we need to wait for those _JavaScript_ to render the texts within the HTML DOM, hence _WebDriverWait_. Let me know if that answers your question.

Comment: @priya Upvote the answer if this/any answer is/was helpful to you for the benefit of the future readers.

Comment: done already thanks , it would be great if you could answer one more question how to locate select element if I don't have name/ id , I am having only onchange parameter in select tag in html code ?